# Apex:CommandButton sending data to controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, commandbutton, custom-controller

I'm trying to create a visual force page with a table and a "request" button that will take the selected row and append it as a task.

Here's a photo of the table:

[image]

When a user hits request, I want to create a task that includes the deal name and deal owner.

Here is the VF page:

```
<apex:page controller="A7_OppsCntrl" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false">   

    <apex:form>
        <table id= 'a7Table' class='display'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Deal Name</th>
                    <th>Deal Owner</th>
                    <th>Request</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
           <apex:repeat value="{!A7Opps}" var="row">
               <tr>
                   <apex:repeat value="{!A7Opps[row]}" var="cell">
                       <td> {!cell} </td>
                   </apex:repeat>
                   <td>
                       <apex:commandButton action="{!send2Admin}" value="Request" title="Send Request to Admin" oncomplete="" reRender="block">
                           <apex:param value="{!A7Opps[row]}" assignTo="{!paramValue}"/>
                       </apex:commandButton>
                   </td>
               </tr>
           </apex:repeat>
         </table>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Here is the controller:

```
Global With Sharing class A7_OppsCntrl {

    string paramValue;

public void setParamValue(string paramValue){
        this.paramValue = paramValue;
    }

    public void send2Admin(){

        user adminId = [SELECT id from user where name like 'Sir Admin' limit 1];
        string userId = toolbox.grabUserId(); //Grabs context user ID
        user userName = [SELECT name from user where id = :userId];

        task leadReq = new task();
        leadReq.OwnerId = adminId.id;
        leadReq.Subject = 'New Request';
        leadReq.Description = userName.name+' is requesting '+this.paramValue;
        insert(leadReq);
    }
```

The task is successfully inserted, but the paramValue comes up as null.

What am I doing incorrectly (probably a lot ;)? How can I get the row data to be appended to the description of the task?

I've tried following this https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000095uXIAQ.

Didn't help me.

Thanks!

UPDATE: It might be helpful to see how the A7Opps mapping works:

```
public static Map<string, list<string>> getA7Opps(){

        List<List<String>> parsedCSV = new List<List<String>>();
        Map<string, list<string>> A7Opps = new Map<string, list<string>>();
        Map<string, list<string>> userA7Opps = new Map<string, list<string>>();

        String fileString = getCSVFromDocs('A7Opps');
        parsedCSV = toolbox.csv2List(fileString, '\\|');
        for (List<String> row : parsedCSV){
          A7Opps.put(row[0], row);
        }

        list<string> targetIDs = new list<string>();
        string userId = toolbox.grabUserId(); 
        targetIDs.add(userId);
        list<deal__c> dealOriginator = [SELECT name, Deal_number__c, owner.id, owner.name 
                                        FROM deal__c 
                                        WHERE owner.id in :targetIDs AND Deal_number__c in :A7Opps.keySet()];

        for(deal__c deal:dealOriginator){
            A7Opps.get(deal.Deal_Number__c).add(deal.name);
            A7Opps.get(deal.Deal_Number__c).add(deal.owner.name);
            userA7Opps.put(deal.Deal_Number__c, A7Opps.get(deal.Deal_Number__c));   
        }
        return userA7Opps;
    }
```

EDIT:
I've updated the controller code to:

```
 public String paramValue {get; set;}

    public static void send2Admin(){

        user adminId = [SELECT id from user where name like 'Sir Admin' limit 1];
        string userId = toolbox.grabUserId();
        user userName = [SELECT name from user where id = :userId];

        task leadReq = new task();
        leadReq.OwnerId = adminId.id;
        leadReq.Subject = 'New Lead Request';
        leadReq.Description = userName.name+' is requesting '+ paramValue; //this doesn't work
        insert(leadReq);

    }
```

paramValue cannot be referenced in the method send2Admin(), the var doesn't exist...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
string paramValue;
```

to this

```
public String paramValue {get; set;}
```

and completely removing

```
public void setParamValue(string paramValue){
    this.paramValue = paramValue;
}
```

also add a "name" attribute to your  tag like so

```
<apex:param name="whatever" value="{!a7Opps[row]}" assignTo="{!paramValue}" />
```

Comment: By switching, I now can't access paramValue from the send2Admin method. I thought something like this.paramValue might work, but nope.

Comment: @ZAR Can you show the code for the A7Opps map, with the Keys and Values as well?

Comment: It's just a bunch of lists of string parsed from a CSV.

Comment: @ZAR  Check out my updated post.  It looks like you need to specify the individual strings, rather than pass a the list of strings.

Comment: Changing to public string paramValue {get;set;} doesn't allow the method send2Admin to access the var paramValue. What else do I need to add so that paramValue can be referenced in the method? Also, switching to row[0] won't work I don't think.. I'll add the A7Opps map code.

Comment: @ZAR Add a "name" attribute to the param tag. I've updated my answer again.  You're right that the row[0] won't work, I was being stupid in saying that.  As for the public String paramValue {get; set;} is just a short form setter method for the paramValue.

Comment: Wooooooaaaaaahhhhhhh! It worked!!!!! Why???

Comment: @ZAR  Honestly, I have no idea, but I'm happy you could get your code working.

Answer (score 0):

Have u gone throught this link???

[enter link description here](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/4-ways-to-pass-parameter-from-jsf-page-to-backing-bean/)

Here JEFF DOUGLAS describe in a fantastic manner..

cherrs!

Comment: Can't see link - just see "enter link description"

Comment: Now check bro i edited my post

Comment: First suggestion on the page doesn't work in SF.

Answer (score 0):

two tips:

1.- Change "A7Opps[row]" for "row"

2.- **static** string paramValue;

let me know if it works.

Comment: Changed to static - got this error: Class static variable cannot be accessed via object instance

Comment: Change the method to static too:
public static void send2Admin(){

Comment: If method is static, it cannot access paramValue - I get this error: "Variable does not exist: this.paramValue"

Comment: Of course. You need to erase "this."  You cannot acces "this" because is static and there is no object instance.

Comment: So no error but paramValue is again showing "null". Back to the original problem